# Compare string to multiple strings in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to know if there is no text string in the variables.
And then compare if there is another text string.
The variables `results` It may contain the following: yes, no or ?
I have follow code:

```
internet = result1
vpn = result2
zetas = result3

values = [internet, vpn, zetas]

    if any(v !== "?" for v in values):
        print("No exist ?")
    if any(v == "no" for v in values):
        print("Exist a NO")
    else:
        print("Good")
```

especially to see the most elegant way of doing this.

Comment: Can you please use some examples to demonstrate what you're trying to do and what the expected output is?

Comment: It looks like you are looking for [elif](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements). And also, there is no `!==`. Use `==` or `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

you can check `value in list` or `value not in list`

```
values = (internet, vpn, zetas)

if "?" not in values:
    print("No exist ?")
if "no"  in values:
    print("Exist a NO")
else:
    print("Good")
```

Answer (score 1):

First it is preferable to pass generator expressions instead of lists for loop feeding.

Secondly, although there can be many ways,, a good way would simply be:

```py
values = (internet, vpn, zetas)
if "?" in (v for v in values):
  print("No exist ?")
```

Generator expressions save memory and time, not critical for the script in hand but useful for larger chunks of data.

Comment: instead of `(v for v in values)` you can use `values` - `if "?" in values:`

Comment: That's right! But this way it will prevent "?" inside strings from escaping detection, I thought it would be a nice feature!

Comment: `(v for v in values)` and `values` will work the same so there is no feature.

Comment: That's actually not correct. But you can try it.

```python
values = ["qwerty", "asdf"]

if "qwert" in values:

  print('1')

if "qwert" in (v for v in values):

  print('2')
```

You will see that it will print 2.

Comment: My python print nothing for both versions. And this is correct result because there is no `"qwert"` on list `["qwerty", "asdf"]`. If I use `if "qwerty"` in both versions then I see `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 0):

I checked if the query you had regarding the question mark in inverted commas would escape detection using an array comparison `[x in B for x in A]`

```
#I assigned values to your variables to test
result1 ='?'
result2="no"
result3 = "yes"

internet = result1
vpn = result2
zetas = result3

#created an array with above values in it both in string format and as variable values (appended a number just for test)
A = [internet, 'no', '?', 'yes', vpn, zetas, '8']

#array of sample strings
B = ['?', 'no', 'yes']

exists = [x in B for x in A]
print (exists)
```

When the results of the comparison printed it gave: [True, True, True, True, True, True, False]. However if there were additional quote marks, e.g. `'"?"'` , the comparison on this printed as False. (Items in single quotes evaluate the same as double quotes..)

Feel free to run/re-assign values/test etc as you please. (might not be the answer you're looking for but hope it helps)